# How to add roles to asp.net 2015 webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, roles

I want to add roles to webfroms in asp.net 2015. You know that 'asp.net configuration' is not exist in this version of visual studio. So how to add roles, one for users and another for admins?

Comment: There's no such thing as "ASP.NET 2015". And the Website Administration Tool has been gone for a long time. You'll need to either write your own code to manage this data, or find a library, or find another tool to do it for you.

Comment: Asking for me to reccomend a library isn't on-topic here at Stack Overflow. But a simple Google search for "website administration tool replacement" should get you started.